# Call Flutter method on iOS when terminated app receives silent push notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I have a Flutter app that needs to send a local notification when a silent notification comes. Everything works on Android but on iOS the method is not triggered when the app is in a terminated state.

Tried using `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` but is working only when the app was sent in background recently.

```
Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");

}

class FirebaseApi {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future<String?> initNotifications() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);

    // get the token [for development only!]
    var fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print('FCM Token: $fcmToken');

    //initNotifications();

    return fcmToken;

  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

In IOS when the app is terminated, the app's code doesn't execute directly, it's the notification payload and structure that triggers the notification to be displayed -**So ensure the structure of the notification you are sending is valid for background notification to trigger**.

You can execute any code after this notification is tapped by a user and the app is lunched.
**Also make sure background fetch is enabled for IOS** for your app as below[image: background nodes for app]

Comment: Hello Steven, I already did enabled Background fetch and Remote notification. My problem is that when I want to send a silent notification (eg.: from Postman), a Firebase function to be executed. This happens only when the app is in background for first 60 seconds.